# ransack sort by model method that returns an integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

I'm trying to figure out how to sort by a method on my model that returns an integer.

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :questions

  def questions_count
    questions.count
  end
end
```

I'd like to be able to sort by the `questions_count` method in my table using ransack.

I have tried `<th><%= sort_link @q, :questions_count %></th>` with no luck.

Is this even possible? How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sort_link helper method can only accept an attribute or the attribute of an association, but if you wish to simple return a count of associated records, this is possible using an existing rails mechanism.

The easiest way to achieve this is by using `counter_cache` - a way to count the number of objects that belong to an associated model. You'll have to add this to the association in your business model like this:

```
has_many :questions, counter_cache: true
```

It also requires a database column in the businesses table called `questions_count`, however, you can actually customise the name of this (and this is what will enable you to pass the number of questions to the sort_link method).

Once this is set up you should be able to call the sort_link helper method without an issue.

```
sort_link @q, :questions_count
```

Find more about counter_cache [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Alternatively, there is 'another' way to achieve this. You can define a `ransacker` instead. You can use it to explicitly write a SQL statement that can perform a COUNT function on all associated questions for a business, but I don't think its as convenient a solution as the counter_cache method. Mainly because the SQL statement would redefine/replace the questions_count method functionality.

Find more about ransackers [here](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/using-ransackers).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can sort using something like `@collection.sort_by{|item| item.method_name}`. Just replace "@collection" by your set of items and "method_name" by the method you want to sort

Comment: the @collection is the result of your ransack search. Something like Model.search(params).sort_by{|item| item.method_name}

Comment: But that will sort every time, I only want it to sort when the sort link is clicked.

Comment: Ive been giving this a shot and it doesnt seem to be sorting it either.